# Stopping an epoll runloop with kthread_stop

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, kernel-module, epoll

I'm using epoll in a kernel module.

I'm creating a kthread on `module_init`, and I want to stop it on `module_exit`.

However, this thread is always almost waiting in `epoll_wait`.

In my exit function, how can I stop the created thread even if it's waiting in `epoll_wait`?

This is my attempt, but every now and then it hangs, I assume because the interrupt doesn't get to the thread before `kthread_stop` does.

```c
struct task_struct *thread;
bool should_stop = false;
static int __init init(void)  {
    thread = kthread_run(run, NULL, "hora");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit exit(void)  {
    l("end");

    should_stop = true;
    force_sig(SIGUSR1, thread);
    l("kthread_stop");
    kthread_stop(thread);

    l("ended");
}

int run(void *data) {
    ...
    while (true) {
        int nfd = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
        l("got event");
        if (should_stop) {
            l("should_stop");
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    l("closed");
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        schedule();
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    }
    set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
    l("exiting");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
end
kthread_stop
got event
should_stop
closed
exiting
ended
```

I've looked into eventfd as an alternative to sending a signal, but it's quite a bit of work (only a couple of eventfd functions are exported) and I don't know for sure whether it'll solve this.

Any insights and help much appreciated.

Comment: It should not be possible to unload a module as long as userspace has some open file. Didn't you set the `owner` of your `file_operations`?

Comment: I am interested how you call =epoll_wait= in a kernel module.